# visudo: specified editor (./sudo_editor) doesn't exist

Tags: command-line, system-installation, visudo

I tried to run the 
"sudo EDITOR=./sudo_editor visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/relax_requirements"
command and the error came out as:
visudo: specified editor (./sudo_editor) doesn't exist

Anyone know what I should do in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You could just edit your sudo files with any editor, `visudo` just does it "in a safe fashion" to guard against some errors. But you can DIY with any editor, just keep a backup copy handy and a live iso ready to fix any errors just in case.

`man visudo` says:

```
 There is a hard-coded list of one or more editors that visudo will use
 set at compile-time that may be overridden via the editor sudoers Default
 variable.  This list defaults to /usr/local/bin/vi.  Normally, visudo
 does not honor the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables unless they
 contain an editor in the aforementioned editors list.  However, if visudo
 is configured with the --with-env-editor option or the env_editor Default
 variable is set in sudoers, visudo will use any the editor defines by
 VISUAL or EDITOR.  Note that this can be a security hole since it allows
 the user to execute any program they wish simply by setting VISUAL or
 EDITOR.
```

So maybe your `visudo` can't override it's hard-coded list of editors. You could try refering to the editor with it's complete path, instead of `./` and that might work, or try a "default" editor like `vi` or `nano` (find their path with `which`). Or just running this worked for me (though I can't recommend `vi` ;-)

```
sudo EDITOR=vi visudo
```

Or

```
sudo EDITOR=nano visudo
```

Or even using a nice graphic editor like `gedit` if it's installed:

```
sudo EDITOR=gedit visudo
```

On a regular Ubuntu, (or Linux Mint & others too) just running this alone should work too:

```
sudo visudo
```

Or in your specific file's case:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/relax_requirements
```

Comment: uummm i typed in your command and like i dont even know what to do cos theres like a list??

Comment: So the command worked and you can use `visudo` now? That's good news, your original question is answered at least, now you can accept (check-mark) the answer if it worked.

Comment: And you mean the sudoers file itself is confusing? I agree :-) You can look at `man sudoers` or `man sudo` for more info. Or you can ask a new question, asking exactly what you're trying to do, that might be easier

Comment: i typed in the "sudo EDITOR=./sudo_editor visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/relax_requirements" and it said that it was busy then i closed the other tabs and it now it says that it doesnt exist i am confused please help me... is it very necessary to keep adding new questions?

Comment: I thought the "specified editor doesn't exist" question was answered? Using "`sudo EDITOR=nano visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/relax_requirements`" might be easier than using `vi` too, but `vi` and `nano` should be on Ubuntu... And visudo is supposed to "lock" the files so they can't be edited by 2 different programs at the same time. You can look for other running `visudo` programs with `"pgrep -l visudo"` and only run one at a time (can kill others with "`sudo pkill visudo`" but if it's been suspended then closing the terminal or `fg` should finish it off.

Comment: ok sorry it's my fault... basically what i am trying to do is trying to install Chromium OS via terminal using this link: "http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/quick-start-guide" and I'm at number 3 "sudoers configuration" and the thing is that the editor command is not working and i do not know how to figure it out

Comment: hello? @Xen2050 please help me

Comment: Hi, I think I've answered this question (about getting visudo to work), and I know nothing about Chromium OS. If you just wanted `chromium-browser` it should be in the default Ubuntu software repositories. That link has crazy over-compicated instructions about just editing a sudoers file, I *think* it just does this: `echo -e "Defaults !tty_tickets\nDefaults timestamp_timeout=180" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers.d/relax_requirements` But askubuntu.com is a "one-at-a-time" question site, you can accept (check-mark) this one and ask a new question about Chromium OS